# How to combine list of objects to single object java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects and I want to combine all object and create single object with all details, this is my class

```
public class Customer {

private String name;
private String address;
private Integer salary;
private Integer yearOfBirth;
private String city;
private String gender;
private Integer age; 

}
```

Let's say I have list like this:

```
List<Customer> customers =  new ArrayList<>();
customers.add(new Customer("ABC", "QWE", null, null, null, null, null));
customers.add(new Customer(null, null, 12345, 1995, null, null, null));
customers.add(new Customer(null, null, null, null, "zxcv", "M", 12));
```

I want to create single object with all details like:

```
Customer customer = Customer("ABC", "QWE", 12345, 1995, "zxcv", "M", 12);
```

How can I achieve this result using java? I can't think any elegant solution!

Comment: What should you do if two of the Customers have conflicting data (For example if the first value is "ABC" for one Customer, and "DEF" for the first value on the second Customer)?

Comment: @sorifiend It will not happen in my case.

Comment: Surely there is a way to change the code so that you do not end up in this position in the first place? If you want a quick and nasty solution simply use `Customer customer = new Customer(customers.get(0).getName(), customers.get(1).getAddress(), customers.get(2).getSalary(), ...);` you'll need to add getter methods to the Customer class, or make the values public.

Comment: `I can't think any elegant solution!` - You can start by providing the solution you have and explaining why do you consider it to be unsatisfactory. If you didn't manage to get it working, then at list show us where you got stuck.

Comment: I also thought same way as sorifiend but some time we will not get all details like we will get name, address, city, gender, age but not salary and yearOfBirth. Then in that case we will have only 2 objects in list.

Comment: Then you could add something like a merge method to the Customer class that takes another Customer as an input and adds any non null values to the current object. `public void merge(Customer other){if(other.getName() != null)name = other.getName(); ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Just collect the values out of the List.

```
// A new Customer-object to collect the data
Customer customer = new Customer(null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

// Iterate over the elements of the customer-List
foreach (Customer tmp : customers)
{
    // take the values out of the current element if not null
    customer.name    = (tmp.name    == null) ? customer.name    : tmp.name;
    customer.address = (tmp.address == null) ? customer.address : tmp.address;
    // ...
}
```

At the end, the `customer` object will have collected the values out of the list-members.
If there are more then one values found, it'll take the last one.